# Why are my details not loading from my XML document into my table?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE member
[
<!ELEMENT member (urn, forename, surname, dob, email)>
]>
<member>
<urn>#######</urn>
<forename>name</forename>
<surname>surname</surname>
<dob>##/##/###</dob>
<email>email@domain.co.uk</email>

</member>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">View my details</button>
<br><br>
<table id="myDeets"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/data/member_6426374.xml", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
var i;
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var table="<tr><th>URN</th><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>DOB</th>            <th>Email</th></tr>";
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
table += "<tr><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("urn")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("forename")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("surname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
 x[i].getElementsByTagName("dob")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td></tr>";
 }
  document.getElementById("myDeets").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
```

Basically i have a button, when this button is pressed a table should form containing the information from my xml document.
When i press the button this forms but my details are not loaded into the table colums:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/cba0a5a349f04d6582ee8f5624ad3527.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this code you got there:

```
<!DOCTYPE member
[
<!ELEMENT member (urn, forename, surname, dob, email)>
]>
```

I don't think this a valid XML definition.

Your error seems to be the base member selection from the xml file:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
```

change it to this:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("member");
```

**Sample XML data file "member_6426374.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<member>
    <urn>#######</urn>
    <forename>name</forename>
    <surname>surname</surname>
    <dob>##/##/###</dob>
    <email>email@domain.co.uk</email>
</member>
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">View my details</button>
<br><br>
<table id="myDeets"></table>
```

**Javascript**

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "member_6426374.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table = "<tr><th>URN</th><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>DOB</th>            <th>Email</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("member");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("urn")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("forename")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("surname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("dob")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("myDeets").innerHTML = table;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**EDIT**

Also make sure, the xml file `/data/member_6426374.xml` exists under the root directory of the domain:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/data/member_6426374.xml", true);
```